# What can be done with Ruby which can't be done with C# 4.0?

Tags: ruby, programming-languages, c#-4.0, .net-4.0

I just finished reading the Ruby chapter of the book [7 Languages in 7 Weeks](http://pragprog.com/titles/btlang/seven-languages-in-seven-weeks). Aside from some syntactic sugar here and I can't really see anything which can't be done with C# with a similar syntax. I do understand both languages are inherently different, but my question relates to its usage rather than design.

Relevant questions make me believe Ruby offers little more than C#:

- [Why aren't c# programmers drawn to ruby as java programmers are?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052254/why-arent-c-programmers-drawn-to-ruby-as-java-programmers-are/3052282#3052282)
- [Is Ruby's code block same as C#'s lambda expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4331714/590790)

I hardly worked with Ruby and my understanding of the language is still very limited, so perhaps somebody who experimented with both .NET 4.0 and Ruby can answer with concrete examples.

**Which tasks require significantly less work with Ruby than C# 4.0?**

---

For those interested, since the question got closed here, [I tried again on Programmers.SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/71905/15464), and accepted an answer there.

Comment: With Ruby you can make beautiful cakes!

Comment: Community Wiki or Programmers.SE instead? I wasn't sure, still I believe there could be an actual answer(s) to this question.

Comment: @Steven Jeuris - even on Programmers.SE this will probably get closed. As for Community Wiki - it is dead for questions. See here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67581/community-wiki-checkbox-missing-in-action

Comment: Run on rails? Seriously this question appears to add nothing to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052254 which you referenced.

Comment: @Ben: Where in that question can I find specific language features which aren't possible in C#?

Comment: As a newbie that is just starting to get his feet wet with Ruby, but has a solid C# background, I would LOVE to see some good answers to this question.

Comment: @Steven Jeuris: That wasn't the question. The question was "what can be done in Ruby but not C#", not "what language features does Ruby have that C# does not". The answer is "Nothing".

Comment: @Ben: I already rephrased to clarify the question.

Answer (score -1):

Both languages are Turing complete, so you can do exactly the same with both of them.

However I think some tasks will require less work in Ruby, and some in C#.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Which tasks in particular would require significantly less work?

Comment: For example create desktop application with windows user interface in C# require less work - it has all features integrated. In Ruby for example, solution of Euler 1 problem is very simple: (1...1000).select {|x| x % 3 == 0 || x % 5 == 0}.inject {|sum, n| sum + n} (by Hosiawak)

Comment: @Esse: You mean `Enumerable.Range(1, 1000).Where(x => x % 3 == 0 || x % 5 == 0).Sum()`?

Comment: @Slaks: Probably, it was first example that came into my head ;)

Comment: Is there really something that Ruby can substantially more succintly than C#?  (I don't know Ruby)

Comment: @SLaks: Hence the question, it would be a pity if it would get closed, then I'll try again on Programmers, or I hope it get merged there.

Comment: @Slaks: problem is I don't know C# very good, so it's hard for me to find good examples ;) But I would say whole metaprogramming in Ruby: http://ruby-metaprogramming.rubylearning.com/ and of course Rails.